# Get Object Properties By Predefined Property Names Array

Tags: javascript

I am pretty sure about this kind of question answered before, but I couldn't make good search.

I have an array of object like;

```
[
  { prop1:"foo1", prop2:"baz1", prop3:"bar1", prop4:"qux1"}
  { prop1:"foo2", prop2:"baz2", prop3:"bar2", prop4:"qux2"}
  { prop1:"foo3", prop2:"baz3", prop3:"bar3", prop4:"qux3"}
]
```

And I have an array which is storing needed property names like;

```
[ "prop1", "prop2" ]
```

So I need to filter all of my objects in array with the property names which is given by another array. And the output will be like;

```
[   
 { prop1:"foo1", prop2:"baz1" }   
 { prop1:"foo2", prop2:"baz2" }  
 { prop1:"foo3", prop2:"baz3" } 
]
```

How can I do this in proper way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `reduce()`

```js
const data = [
  { prop1:"foo1", prop2:"baz1", prop3:"bar1", prop4:"qux1"},
  { prop1:"foo2", prop2:"baz2", prop3:"bar2", prop4:"qux2"},
  { prop1:"foo3", prop2:"baz3", prop3:"bar3", prop4:"qux3"}
];

const props = [ "prop1", "prop2" ];

const res = data.map(e => props.reduce((a,c) => (a[c] = e[c] , a), {}));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Nice solution, could you please use more explicit variable names for the sake of readability? I understand the point of having a one liner, but reduce's params are obscure enough (upvoting anyway)

Comment: @axelduch `a` is accumulator, `c` is current element. Docs outline what arguments are

Comment: I was rather saying that for those unfamiliar with reduce. It doesn't have to be scary to them :) But fair enough - people curious enough about it will check the doc anyway

Answer (score 4):

You can create `pick` function with `reduce` method and then use it with `map` method.

```js
const data = [{ prop1:"foo1", prop2:"baz1", prop3:"bar1", prop4:"qux1"},{ prop1:"foo2", prop2:"baz2", prop3:"bar2", prop4:"qux2"},{ prop1:"foo3", prop2:"baz3", prop3:"bar3", prop4:"qux3"}]
const props = [ "prop1", "prop2" ]

const pick = (o, p) => p.reduce((r, e) => Object.assign(r, {[e]: o[e]}), {})
const res = data.map(o => pick(o, props));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like below to achieve the result:

```js
const data = [
  { prop1:"foo1", prop2:"baz1", prop3:"bar1", prop4:"qux1"},
  { prop1:"foo2", prop2:"baz2", prop3:"bar2", prop4:"qux2"},
  { prop1:"foo3", prop2:"baz3", prop3:"bar3", prop4:"qux3"},
]

const keys = [ "prop1", "prop2" ]

let result = data.map((record) => {
  let obj = {}
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    obj[key] = record[key]
  })
  return obj
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [
  { prop1:"foo1", prop2:"baz1", prop3:"bar1", prop4:"qux1"},
  { prop1:"foo2", prop2:"baz2", prop3:"bar2", prop4:"qux2"},
  { prop1:"foo3", prop2:"baz3", prop3:"bar3", prop4:"qux3"}
]

let filter = [ "prop1", "prop2" ];

let out = [...arr].map(e => Object.keys(e).map(k => !filter.includes(k) ? delete e[k] :true) && e);
console.log(out)
```